# removing deleted folders with git

Tags: git, rm

I am running

```
git status
```

And I have a massive laundry list of deleted files that I need to remove with

```
git rm
```

the problem is I need to delete them all in one command, and the list is too long to select them all. Is there a way to automatically sync git so it permanently removes them all? Below is an example output log:

```
    deleted:    everest-web/rails/railties/test/generators/system_test_generator_test.rb
deleted:    everest-web/rails/railties/test/generators/task_generator_test.rb
deleted:    everest-web/rails/railties/test/generators/test_runner_in_engine_test.rb
deleted:    everest-web/rails/railties/test/generators_test.rb
deleted:    everest-web/rails/railties/test/initializable_test.rb
deleted:    everest-web/rails/railties/test/isolation/abstract_unit.rb
deleted:    everest-web/rails/railties/test/json_params_parsing_test.rb
deleted:    everest-web/rails/railties/test/minitest/rails_plugin_test.rb
deleted:    everest-web/rails/railties/test/path_generation_test.rb
deleted:    everest-web/rails/railties/test/paths_test.rb
deleted:    everest-web/rails/railties/test/rack_logger_test.rb
deleted:    everest-web/rails/railties/test/rails_info_controller_test.rb
deleted:    everest-web/rails/railties/test/rails_info_test.rb
deleted:    everest-web/rails/railties/test/railties/engine_test.rb
deleted:    everest-web/rails/railties/test/railties/generators_test.rb
deleted:    everest-web/rails/railties/test/railties/mounted_engine_test.rb
deleted:    everest-web/rails/railties/test/railties/railtie_test.rb
deleted:    everest-web/rails/railties/test/secrets_test.rb
deleted:    everest-web/rails/railties/test/test_unit/reporter_test.rb
deleted:    everest-web/rails/railties/test/version_test.rb
deleted:    everest-web/rails/tasks/release.rb
deleted:    everest-web/rails/tasks/release_announcement_draft.erb
deleted:    everest-web/rails/tools/README.md
deleted:    everest-web/rails/tools/console
deleted:    everest-web/rails/tools/line_statistics
deleted:    everest-web/rails/tools/profile
deleted:    everest-web/rails/tools/test.rb
deleted:    everest-web/rails/version.rb
```

Comment: It not clear what you are asking, as the files are already marked as deleted in your 'git status', so you don't need to do git rm anymore. Maybe you want to commit those deletions ?

Comment: I guess what I meant is that these deletions are not reflected in the github remote repo.

Comment: You need to commit _and_ push in that case.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to delete all file in current directory  first

```
git add .
```

then you need to remove a all files  for that you need run below command

```
git rm -f *
git status
```

> while running above command you should be in your working directory (current directory)

Comment: would the same logic apply for adding instead of removing?

Comment: for adding a files we have 3 commands
1 . git add . --> adds all modified and new (untracked) files in the current directory and all subdirectories to the staging area

2 . git add / --> it will add from root directory 

3. git add * --> it will add all files to staging

Answer (score 0):

**For Git 1.x**

```
$ git add -u
```

This tells git to automatically stage tracked files -- including deleting the previously tracked files.

**For Git 2.0**

To stage your whole working tree:

```
$ git add -u :/
```

To stage just the current path:

```
$ git add -u .
```

ref : [here](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/How-to-delete-multiples-files-in-Github/td-p/4623)

Comment: Is there a way to git add to track all files?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the git man page:

> If all you really want to do is to remove from the index the files that are no longer present in the working tree (perhaps because your working tree is dirty so that you cannot use git commit -a), use the following command:

```
       git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D -z | xargs -0 git rm --cached
```

Comment: I think this is the wrong answer and stan is more correct.